# Spark JDBC DB partitioning when there is no incremental ID partitioncolumn

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I used the following logic in my DB fetch:

```
    properties.setProperty("partitionColumn", "ID");
        System.out.println("lowerBound="+ bounds[0]); **-> 15555345 **
        System.out.println("upperBound="+ bounds[1]); **-> 37543455662** 
        properties.setProperty("lowerBound", bounds[0]); 
        properties.setProperty("upperBound", bounds[1]);
        properties.setProperty("numPartitions", "3");
        properties.setProperty("fetchsize", "100");
        properties.setProperty("Driver", driver);
```

I have a dB with about 1000 rows in my dev env with data as shown below:
lowerbound = 15555345
I have 950 rows with ID 15555345 15555346, 15555347 etc.,
upperbound =37543455662
I have 5 rows going backwards from 37543455662, 37543455661 etc.,

Even though my partition column is incremental, due to selection criteria and distribution of the records; what I am selecting is not sequential as shown above. With a simple 3 partition code, I see one executor executing 950 records, and the second executing 50, 3rd sitting idle.

How do I make sure my db workload is evenly distributed?

Second related question -- should my numberOfDBPartitions match number of executors?
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

i was using ORACLE DB, so was able to use Oracle's ROWNUM to generate a number sequence as a select column, and used that as my partition column. this made sure my DB partitions are equally split. After the following change I see 300, 300, 400 as my DB split. Hope this will help someone who is also facing this problem:

...

```
    String table = "(select col.*, ROWNUM as rowNumber from (select * from myTableName) col) myTable";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("partitionColumn", "rowNumber");
    properties.setProperty("lowerBound", "0");
    properties.setProperty("upperBound", getTotalRowCount(criteria));
    properties.setProperty("numPartitions", "3");
    properties.setProperty("fetchsize", "100");
    properties.setProperty("Driver", driver);

    properties.setProperty("user", user);
    properties.setProperty("password", password);
    Dataset<Row> records = SparkSession.getActiveSession().get().read().jdbc(jdbcUrl, table, properties);
    ...
```